# 3 screens attached, only 2 have image

Tags: ubuntu, amd-radeon

I have an (old) computer with Ubuntu 20.04 (with cinnamon) on a Asus M4A88T-M motherboard. It has 3 onboard graphics outputs; VGA, DVI and HDMI. I'm using for years both the VGA and DVI (split screen). However i want to attach a 3d screen to it with HDMI.
When i connect a screen with HDMI, my DVI screen goes 'off' and the HDMI works correctly (it takes over the output of my DVI screen). I cannot enable the DVI screen, e.g. if i detect screens it does see my HDMI screen but not my DVI screen.
If i then unplug my HDMI screen, my DVI screen automatically goes on again, and takes the output of the HDMI output.

It looks like that only VGA and DVI/HDMI can be used; not in a 3way output. In the bios there is no such setting to enable/disable multi-monitor setup.
I also cannot install the ati catalyst driver/center, because my installation is to new (kernel > 3.9 and XServer > 1.10).

Any idea how to connects three screen, based on the ATI Radeon HD 4250 chipset, with Linux?

Comment: What resolutions and frequencies are your three screens? What is your VRAM amount (see [link](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/video-ram-windows-10/))?

Answer (score 0):

It's not unusual at all to find low-end graphics with 3 sockets but only 2 supported displays. One pair is sharing circuitry, usually DVI/HDMI. You'd have to look up the manufacturer's spec to be certain.
It's very unlikely to be a driver issue, it's hardware, 'as designed'.

[Asus' website](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A88TM/) neatly ducks the issue…

> HDMI/DVI/RGB Support
>
> Flexible Graphics Alternatives
> This motherboard supports multiple
> digital and analog display output interfaces - HDMI, DVI, and D-Sub.
> With such diversity of display outputs, you are able to choose and
> upgrade display devices freely.

Comment: HDMI is actually a DVI ([TMDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition-minimized_differential_signaling)) signal + some extras. It's almost certain that both of those ports use the same circuitry when it comes to onboard graphics. Especially if they are in the same "stack" on the rear I/O panel.

Comment: Yup - I wasn't going to get technical, but it's not surprising to see manufacturers skimping on low-end gear. They often do the same with such as Open GL support - meaning games work on the primary but get glitchy on a secondary [I spent 10 years working gaming support, I've discovered many of their money-saving tricks] ;)